# react did not render all rows and just rendered one object and reapeated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

it should populate all rows to the table (the rows are from from the api is an array of objects) currently the issue is only render that last object of the array and I have no idea why it keeps on repeating , as you can see on the screenshot it only loads 1 object and then repeats that is why all the rows have the same value.

By the way the rows or the data from the api is an array of objects /

Maybe someone has an idea on how we can address this issue. Thanks.

#rows from the api result from the console log this is the rows that is been feed to the grid

#react code

```
export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)`
    .MuiDataGrid-row: nth-of-type(odd) {
      background: #E3E0E0
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-cell {
      border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader  {
      border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator--sideRight {
      display: none
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer {
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer  {
      visibility: visible;
      width: auto;
    }
`;

const PortfolioPage: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { isPending, isError, isSuccess, grid, isSaveSuccess } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.region
  );
  const [snackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState<IRegional | null>(null)

  const rows = grid ? grid.items : [];

  console.log('rows' , rows)


  const fetchGridItems = () => {
     const payload: IPageListApiRequestPayload = {
        accountId: 1,
        sortKey: JSON.stringify([]),
        sortOrder: JSON.stringify([]),
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 100,
        searchString: '',
      };
      dispatch(getRegionGrid(payload));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    // Save success
    if (isSaveSuccess) {
      setSnackbarOpen(true);
      fetchGridItems();
    }
  }, [isSaveSuccess])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      fetchGridItems();
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  const renderList = (data: IEmail) => (
    <div style={{display: 'block'}}>
        <div>Full Name: {data.firstName} {data.lastName}</div>
        <div>Email Address: {data.emailAddress}</div>
    </div>
  )

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "associateDirectorofConstructionOps",
      headerName: "Associate Director of Construction Ops",
      minWidth: 300,
      flex: 0.16,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
        <>
           {
             params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps ? params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps.map((prop: IEmail) => renderList(prop))
              : null
           }
        </>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const fixedColumnLeft: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "regionName",
      headerName: "Region Division",
      flex: 0.08,
      minWidth: 100,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
    {
      field: "subRegionName",
      headerName: "Sub-Region",
      flex: 0.15,
      minWidth: 50,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
    {
      field: "marketName",
      headerName: "Market",
      flex: 0.08,
      minWidth: 50,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
  ];
  const fixedColumnRight: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "action",
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      sortable: false,
      renderHeader: () => <></>,
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
        <div
          style={{
            color: "rgb(110 110 110)",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <EditIcon onClick={() => handleClickOpen(params)} />
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleClickOpen = (data: any) => {
    setSelectedRow(data.row);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: "100vh", background: "#EEEAEA" }}>
      <Snackbar
        open={snackbarOpen}
        autoHideDuration={3000}
        onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)}>
        <Alert onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              Successfully saved!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <EditProperties open={open} handleClose={handleClose} selectedRow={selectedRow} />
      <DashboardWrapper seoProps={{
        title: "PIM | Regions",
        }}
        title="Properties"
        mainClass="properties-page">
        {isError ? <div>Error Loading Regions!</div> : ""}
        {isPending ? <>Loading Regions...</> : ""}
        {isSuccess ? (
        <>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                width: "636px",
                height: "56px",
                background: "rgba(37, 36, 41, 0.9)",
                padding: "8px 16px 8px 8px",
                borderBottomRightRadius: "30px",
              }}
            >
              <Input
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: "461px",
                  height: "40px",
                  background: "#FFFFFF",
                  borderRadius: "4px",
                  outline: "none",
                }}
                placeholder="Search  by typing property name or address"
                startAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
              />
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  color: "#FFFFFF",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginRight: "10px",
                }}
              >
                <TuneIcon style={{ fontSize: "32px" }} />
                <span style={{ fontSize: "10px", marginTop: "-5px" }}>
                  Filters
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{ marginTop: "24px" }}>
              <div
                style={{
                  borderBottom: "1px solid #C4C4C4",
                  padding: "16px",
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  background: "#FFFFFF",
                  height: "72px",
                }}
              >
                <label
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: "600",
                    fontSize: "24px",
                    color: "#252429",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Regions{" "}
                </label>
                <div
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    color: "#C4C4C4",
                    display: "flex",
                    fontSize: "16px",
                  }}
                >
                  <IosShareIcon style={{ marginRight: "14px" }} />
                  Export
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* Table container */}
              <div style={{position: "relative", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  {/* Left table */}
                  <Box
                    sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                    style={{
                      width: "20%",
                   
                      zIndex: 99,
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                    }}
                  >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      hideFooterPagination={true}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={fixedColumnLeft}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </Box>

                  {/* Center table */}
                <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: '70%'}}>
                  <div style={{ width: '2000px', margin: 'auto', overflow: "hidden"}} >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={columns}
                      pageSize={100}
                      rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50, 100]}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                  {/* Right table */}
                  <Box
                    sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                    style={{
                      width: "10%",
                      zIndex: 99,
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                    }}
                  >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      hideFooterPagination={true}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={fixedColumnRight}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </Box>
              </div>
            </TableContainer>
            {/* <ActionButtonContainer
              btnNameOne="Property"
              btnNameTwo="Properties"
              btnIconOne={<UploadFileIcon />}
              btnIconTwo={<AddIcon />}
            /> */}
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </DashboardWrapper>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Your code is pretty complex and hard to read, at least use something like prettier, or make some code splitting. No offense, but what's the point of having a table container around the datagird, and why do you have two datagrids instead of one

Comment: as you can see on my code there are 3 tables because the table at the middle has 16 columns and I need to make it scrollable so what I did is instead of just using 1 table 1 used 3 so its easier to implement the scroll

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox or a stackblitz instence with a fake json api for us to play around it a little bit?

Comment: I dont know how to use stackblitz Sir , to be honest

Comment: but the main concern just sir is why the rows did not populate on the grid , I think the grid code is pretty simple to readt  , it has columns and it has rows

Comment: jsut dont mind the other part of the code , just look at where the rows are coming from and where it is being loaded

Comment: First, change this `params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps.map` to this `params.value.map`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249459/discussion-between-tim-launders-and-normal).

Comment: where does the params.value coming from ?

Comment: so what is the correct way Sir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because of this

[image]

This line is the cause of all these problems

The `DataGrid` expects a unique key for every row in the table

so it's asking you where it can find that unique key

You're telling it that it can find it inside the `accountId` prop.

Which is not accurate because it has duplicates

Normally this should be id, but it's null everywhere in your case.

If the data source coming from your API has a property called "id", the MUI `DataGrid` is automatically going to use it if you didn't set the `getRowId` prop.

Comment: Hi Sir , Good day , do you have an idea about vertical scroll in the pinned grids ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410307/react-data-grid-pinned-tables-sticky-header